# Search Bar search through numbers and not only names with Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I'm currently trying to search between my contact List and all I can find is looking through names and surnames and not numberPhones. This is my code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
       inSearchMode = true
       filteredData = contactList.filter {
            $0.givenName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil ||
            $0.familyName.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil ||
            $0.phoneNumbers.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil
        }
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And is giving me error:

> Value of type '[CNLabeledValue]' has no member 'range'

How can I solve?

Comment: Are you getting it on `$0.givenName`? Or what other line?

Comment: @Carpsen90 0.phoneNumbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `phoneNumbers` property of `CNContact` isn't a `String`. It's an array of `CNLabeledValue` objects.

You need to scan the array, extracting the `CNPhoneNumber` from each `CNLabeledValue`. Then get the `stringValue` of the phone number. Finally, use `range(of:)` on that string value.

Change:

```
$0.phoneNumbers.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil
```

to:

```
$0.phoneNumbers.contains { $0.value.stringValue.range(of: searchBar.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil }
```

Note that the first `$0` is the `CNContact` from the `contactList` array. The second `$0` is the `CNLabeldValue` from the `phoneNumbers` array of the contact.